# SQL query for child table summary and generalazation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 tables with diagram below
[image]

I want to summary query for the  Institution table. where I want to get result of only,

`InstitutionType ProductName Quantity`

For example. sample data of institution table

```
 Id   Name  Address  InstitionTypeId
  1   aaa   ny132    1001
  2   bbb   dx23     1001  
  3   ccc   bn33     1002
```

And the `InstitionProduct` is like that

```
     Id  ProductId  Quantity  InstitionId
      1   1000       120       1
      2   1000       100       2
      3   1000       50        3
```

Then I want a query result to output total quantity of a given product by Instition Type wise. The sample output will look like this.

```
InstitutionTypeId  productId  quantity
1001               1000        220
1002               1000        50
```

So I want to group the institution by type and aggregate the product quantity of all institution type group.

I tried to use the group by clause, but with the product quantity not as a grouping element it results in error.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  Institution.InstitutionTypeID,
  InstitutionProduct.ProductID,
  SUM(InstitutionProduct.Quantity)
FROM
  Institution
LEFT JOIN
  InstitutionProduct
    ON InstitutionProduct.InstitutionID = Institution.ID
GROUP BY
  Institution.InstitutionTypeID,
  InstitutionProduct.ProductID
```

Comment: Hello, @Dems I want to group all the Institutions with their InstitutionTypeid. I want to sum Product Quantity of all the Institution.Id with same InstitutionTypid

Answer (score 1):

If you are querying with group by you need to use either aggregate functions or group by all included fields. The reason is, that the 'group by' returns exactly one row per 'group by' value, so if you introduce an ungrouped field, this would conflict if the field has more than one value per grouping constraint. Even though this might not be the case for your dataset, the query engine cannot know this, and raises an error.

The solution is to introduce aggregates for all non-grouping field with aggregates being (among others): average (avg), summarize (sum), minimum (min) and maximum (max). This would lead to something like

```
   SELECT i.InstitutionTypeID, i.Institution.ID, SUM(ip.Quantity) 
   FROM Institution I LEFT JOIN InstitutionProduct IP 
         ON IP.InstituationID = I.ID
   GROUP BY i.InstitutionTypeID, i.Institution.ID
```

Comment: @feaster as Demis has corrected above, I don't want the institution.Id field; I want the aggregate by the InstitutionTypeId

Comment: Fine. The point was not the exact query but an attempt to clearify the reason for your reported server response.